# Airflow externaltasksensor not working as expected

Tags: airflow

I currently have a main ELT DAG file running at midnight daily, with this design in mind.

```
start >> extract_load_taskgroup >> transform >> end
```

In the extract_load_taskgroup, it will call external separate extract_load DAG (schedule as none) files for each source system.

When I run this as-is, once extract_load_taskgroup is triggered, it moved straight to transform task without considering whether the different extract_load DAG are executed completely.

So I added a externaltasksensor group

```
start >> extract_load_taskgroup >> externaltasksensor_group >> transform >> end
```

The externaltasksensor_group will have individual externaltasksensor task for each of the extract_load DAG file.

So now, when i try running this, the externaltasksensor is perpetually poking even though the different extract_load DAG file has completed their run.

Asking the collective wisdom here:

1. check_existence -> does that check for the specific DAG instance its gonna poke or just that the DAG / task exist?
2. do i need to align execution date in this pipe setup given that the DAG that i want to sense is triggered by the main ELT dag? if so, how should i go about doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. By default external task sensor will poke for the execution date of your main DAG. You can modify it using `execution_delta` or `execution_delta_fn`.
2. Since your schedule interval is `None` for the second DAG it will have a variable execution date and you will have to calibrate your external task sensor to poke for correct date and time. This isn't feasible.

Use [`TriggerDagRunOperator`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/operators/trigger_dagrun/index.html) in your main DAG and set `wait_for_completion` to `True`.

Comment: omg, how did i missed out this parameter. thanks! fixed the problem.

Comment: if a parent dag is triggering a child dag , and using ExternalTaskSensor to controll once it is "success" status, how would be the configuration of execution time?